# Why did Lagavullian get an extra 4 Metalicize?

Tags: slay-the-spire

Normally when I fight a [Lagavullian](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Lagavulin) it has 8 Metalicize. However, on my recent run it started the fight with an extra 4 Metalicize for a total of 12. This happened on floor 6 and my only relics were Burning Blood and Golden Idol.

Why did Lagavullian start with an extra 4 Metalicize?

[image: Plus 4 Metalicize]

[image: 12 Metalicize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagavullian had an extra 4 Metalicize because of an [Elite Buff](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Elites#Elite_Buffs).

> After unlocking Act 4, until the Emerald Key is obtained, one of the elites in each Act will appear as a burning elite icon. **This 'super elite' will receive one of the following buffs**, and it will drop the Emerald Key when defeated.
>
> - (Act number + 1) increase in Icon Strength Strength.
> - +25% max HP.
> - **(Act number*2 + 2) Icon Metallicize Metallicize.**
> - (Act number*2 + 1) Icon Regen Regenerate.
>
> <sup>Source: [Slay the Spire Wiki](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Elites#Elite_Buffs)</sup>

The usual 8 Metalicize goes away once the Lagavullian has woken up, but the bonus 4 Metalicize will remain for the entire fight.

[image: Elite Buff icon]